# how to capture photo using camara in sdk 3.1?

Tags: iphone

photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; //or album
photoPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;

When I write above syntax then I get warning allowsImageEditing is deprecated in sdk 3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to become acquainted with the [IPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action). The [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW8) is very explicit about what to do here.

> **`allowsImageEditing`**
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the user is allowed to edit a selected image. 
>    (Deprecated. Use **`allowsEditing`** instead.)

Comment: You *really* want to get acquainted with the iPhone Dev Center.  Apple has the best docs on Earth.

Answer (score 3):

I think the property is now just 'allowsEditing'